# Why don't I get the correct number of lines from .txt and also random number does not change

Tags: batch-file, cmd

two things I don't understand what I can do more.

1. `%%C` instead of showing me that in `output-mp3.txt` (`%%B`) I have one single line -> the output is 124000 lines. If I make the `for /f %%C`  alone in another `.bat` is showing me the corect number of lines.
2. I need if `%%C == 1` to get `!exportname!` (`%%~nB`) which is the name of the song and if is not equal with 1 to be generated a random name. My conditional command doesn't work also `%RANDOM%` show all the time the same number when is looped.
3. If someone have a more professional and optimized approach of what I need I will very gladly to hear any directions.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in (mp3list-1.txt) DO (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims='" %%B in (%%A) DO (
        for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< %%B')  do (
            echo %%A
            echo %%B
            echo %%~nB
            echo %%C
            Echo Notepad file has %%C lines and the name of the song is %%~nB
            if "%%C"=="1" (
                set /p exportname=%%~nB 
                Echo Name of the song

            ) else (
                set /p exportname=!RANDOM!
                Echo Random number
            )
            Echo !exportname!
        )
    )
)
```

`mp3list-1.txt` contain

```
F:\.....\Videos-1\output-mp3.txt
```

`output-mp3.txt` in this case `%%B`  contain

```
file 'F:\....\Canal-1\Videos-1\name of the song.mp3'
```

LATER EDIT:

I tried like this also with the third `FOR`, but same not showing me that I have 1 single line .. batch tell me I have 50k  lines, witch is no true...  also changed make some other changes.. no luck ..

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%A in ("mp3list-1.txt") DO (
    for /F "UseBackQ tokens=2 delims='" %%B in ("%%A") DO (
          set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "%%B" | find /C ":""
                 for /f  %%C in ('!cmd!') DO (
            echo %%A
            echo %%B
            echo %%~nB
            echo %%C
            Echo Notepad file has %%C lines and the name of the song is %%~nB
            if "%%C"=="1" (
                set /p exportname=%%~nB 
                Echo Name of the song

            ) else (
                set /p exportname=!RANDOM!
                Echo Random number
            )
            Echo !exportname!
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: 2.) use `!random!` within the loop

Comment: 1.) quote filenames that (might) contain spaces: `"%%B"`

Comment: No spaces involved, i tried "" also i will test Random what you think about not geting the right number of lines from . Txt ?

Comment: Are you sure that `mp3list-1.txt` shouldn't be `"mp3list-1.txt"`?

Comment: `else (` should be `) else (`

Comment: @Compo first two 'for' are working proprely. I tried also with "" is same.  Only the third 'for' that need to show me number of lines not working proprely, instead show me I have 1 linr .. show me random big numbers 124000, 90000 ... etc . As i said the third 'for' if i copy paste in a new .bat is working good. Only in this batch is not working..

Comment: @IonutBejinariu, if the intent is to read each line of content within the file, and you are using `UseBackQ`, you should doublequote the filename. If you aren't doublequoting the filename, then you shouldn't need `UseBackQ` to read each line of content within the file.

Comment: @I changed the code so many times to find the issue and remained like that .. first 'for' its enough 'delims="' to work.. but my problem is the third 'for' in this batch..  hope someone have a solution..

Comment: Your main problem has already been answered in @Stephan's previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043490/why-dont-i-get-the-correct-number-of-lines-from-txt-and-also-random-number-doe#comment132429410_75043490), and was further highlighted by my [Edit]. There is no such command as `Else`, it is simply an extension of the `If` command. As such it needs to be linked to it, not separated from it.

Comment: Is true,, i didn add' )' before else.. but actually my main problem is that my third 'for' not counting the number of the lines corectly from the .txt file. This is where the fire is.. and i need to resolve it..

Comment: I added a new version of batch.. stil having the same issue of counting well the lines in %%C. My output is 50400 and I have just 1 line

Comment: Your last code seems to work fine for me. Except I don't understand the usage of `set /p`. In my world, it doesn't make sense to ask the user and the `/p` should be deleted. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your script and comments/questions do not match I have made some guesses / assumptions.
This is  what your script does:
**%%A** is a line from file 'mp3list-1.txt'
**%%B** is the full path and filename extracted from %%a, this is an mp3 file
**%%C** is the number of lines in the mp3 file! (this is a binary file not text).

Your comments mention a file named 'output-mp3.txt'.
Just for clarity I have added the file output-mp3.txt to keep the changes close to your code.
But the output-mp3.txt is not needed.
Also the check for number of lines is not needed because this file will have just 1 line (**%%B**).
Because this mystery file "output-mp3.txt" is neither created, nor used in your code this is a bit of a guessing game.

```
    @echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in (mp3list-1.txt) DO (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims='" %%B in (%%A) DO (
        > "output-mp3.txt" echo %%B
        rem type "output-mp3.txt"
        rem for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< %%B')  do (
        for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< "output-mp3.txt"')  do (
            echo %%A
            echo %%B
            echo %%~nB
            echo %%C
            Echo Notepad file has %%C lines and the name of the song is %%~nB  **
            if "%%C"=="1" (
                set /p exportname=%%~nB 
                Echo Name of the song

            ) else (
                set /p exportname=!RANDOM!
                Echo Random number
            )
            Echo !exportname!
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I tested, thank you, I have some things to say, please 1.) all the time `%%C` is 1, I modified the output-mp3.txt with more lines... same issue, I also deleted the local files that is generated  2.) second problem for me is the approach. I see a local `output-mp3.txt` is generated, this is not good for me because I am running multiple batch files of this identical code, only having export directories different and different paths in `.txt` files, but name `output-mp3.txt`  is the same all the time for all lines, so there is a conflict with other batch files that I run in same time.

Comment: woow, I didn see that .. I cant believe it .. on find line function not `%%B` must be used .. needs to be `%%A` to count the lines..

Comment: Just remove the line that creates the local file. As I have written in my answer I have added this only to demonstrate that the `%%C` loop works and gets the correct number of lines.